# Is there a way to change the color of .suptitle in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Long story short : default color is black, I like to keep my themes dark in my notebooks as well, I can't find a way to change the suptitle (ie the figure title). I can change the position, the font size, I can change the color of the different figures titles. I can't find how to change the color of subtitle.

Here is a short example of what I would do :

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_dataset.take(1):

    fig.suptitle(label_names[tf.argmax(labels[1])], fontsize=24)

    img = normalize_tensor(images[1])

    ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(img[..., 0].numpy().astype("float"), cmap='inferno')
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title('0')

    ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(img[..., 1].numpy().astype("float"), cmap='inferno')
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title('1')

    ax3 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
    plt.imshow(img[..., 2].numpy().astype("float"), cmap='inferno')
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title('2')

    ax4 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
    plt.imshow(img.numpy().astype("float"))
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title('all')
```

and this is what I would get:

[image: image that I'm not allowed to insert directly yet]

To be extremely clear once again : I would like to choose the color of the text 'Edema'.

If it is not possible, I'd like to know some straightforward workaround, which is probably obvious for an expert pyplot user, which I am clearly not.

Thank you all

Comment: For any text, you can pass the `color` keyword arg to `suptitle` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text

Comment: `fig.suptitle(..., color='gold')`?

Comment: @JodyKlymak thank you, guess I should start to read the doc more carefully

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `color` keyword argument to change the default color in `fig.suptitle`.

```
fig.suptitle(label_names[tf.argmax(labels[1])], fontsize=24, color='red')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).